# How can I change Wishlist 'out of stock' to show 'notify when back in stock'?

Tags: wishlist

I am trying to improve the functionality of the Wishlist so that customers can be notified when out of stock items come back into stock.

I would like to change the out of stock text on the wishlist page to show 'notify when back in stock' and for that button to work.

I have tried to decipher how wishlist and productalert work, I also hoped that I could just post a link to `$product->getSignupUrl()` in `template/wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml`however I am now stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this link to the template you mentioned:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('productalert/add/stock', array(
        'product_id'    => $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getId(),
        Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => Mage::helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl()
    ))?>"><?php echo $this->__('Sign up to get notified when this product is back in stock')?></a>
```

Comment: Genius - there I was getting lost in xml files wondering where the magic url getters came from! Thank you so much! Beer is owed!

Comment: But I did not get any mail from product in stock 
when i was set the product instock